# How shall I rsync changes in directory structure without actually recopying

Tags: rsync, move

I had the folder structure as below
./a/b/c_file synced to the destination ./a/b/c_file

Now I changed the structure in source as ./a/d/e/c_file.

But rsync seems to be delete the old directory structure in destination and create a new one by copying the c_file as new file.

I just want to directory name / file name changes instead of copying or replacing the entire file as they are video files are large and would take long time to replace to the new directory structure.

even to ./a/c_File or ./a....n_directories/c_file as just reorg the directory structure instead of recopying the whole file.

Is there any way to achieve through `rsync / powershell` etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rsync that handles moves sensibly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102620/rsync-that-handles-moves-sensibly)

Answer (score 2):

What I have done a couple of times when I wanted to move huge files and not have my rsync-based backup-script re-copy it, is to make a hardlink in the new location, run the backup-script (the `-H` option to rsync is the important one here) and then remove the old location.

It sounds like you have done the rename/move, then I see two options:

1. Perform the same commands on the target as you used on the source
2. Recreate the old names as hardlinks, run `rsync` with `-H` and remove the old names.