# can rsync recognise files have been moved?

Tags: rsync

Scenario: I back up to external (ext) drive 1 and sync it to ext drive 2 (to have 2 backups). I archived a large directory (dir) on ext drive 1 by moving it into a new dir named 'archive'. Then i synced ext drive 1 to ext drive 2. It took 24hrs to run because it deleted all of the files on ext hd 2 in the old location and then recreated them in the new 'archive' dir. Am i missing some option in rsync to make it recognise they are the same files in a new location?

This is my rsync command:

```
rsync -avxPnh --no-p --exclude-from=.... --itemize-changes --out-format="%i|%n|" --update` --delete exthd1 exthd2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rsync that handles moves sensibly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/102620)

Comment: yes, thanks, it does answer my question. I guess i should delete my question then?